# Why my deserialization is giving me an error Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

```
public List<CoinMarket> GetCoinMarket()
{
    List<CoinMarket> coinMarket = new List<CoinMarket>();
    var URLWebAPI = "http://190.202.54.19/wsZeus/api/Account/Markets/Get";
    try
    {
        using (var Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            var JSON =  Client.GetStringAsync(URLWebAPI);
            coinMarket = (List<CoinMarket>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSON.Result);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"    ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    return coinMarket;
}
```

It is throwing and i do not know why. It looks like there is something wrong with the serialization part. But i verified it.

Comment: Please update the question with the complete exception details. As an aside, you should not block on async code with `.Result`. If your code is not async compatible then don't use `HttpClient`.

Comment: Post the actual error/stacktrace and the JSON response that is produced when you go to http://190.202.54.19/wsZeus/api/Account/Markets/Get

Comment: If you want help with an exception you should provide the exception details including the stack trace. My bet is that you get ad `InvalidCastException`. You will have to use the generic version of `DeserializeObject` to deserialize to a specific type. No, your JSON variable is actually a `Task<T>`...

Comment: @Crowcoder "...then don't use HttpClient" Even in a console application?

Comment: A tip: please format your code better next time, which I have done now. It helps everyone, and especially yourself (to get answers).

Comment: @KennethK. how do you know it is a console app?

Comment: @Crowcoder Well, I don't...but I don't you can safely say it's not either. My point is, your comment makes it sound like you should never use `.Result`. My understanding is that it depends on what kind of synchronization context you're using.

Comment: The error Message is "One or more errors occurred."

Comment: @KennethK. Even if it is a console app that is usually just for prototyping and I just wanted to head off the problem early. Luckily async main is coming to c# soon.

Comment: @Crowcoder HttpClient uses ConfigureAwait(false) when awaiting which means it's safe to call .Result. You won't benefit from it being async, but you won't get a deadlock.

Comment: @Allrameest I doubt it calls ConfigureAwait with false, where do you see that documented? And that is not safe, you can usually get away with it but all the code in the chain also must do that so you can't blindly count on it.

Comment: @IgorMiquilena Looks like an AggregateException. You need to look at the InnerExceptions property to see the actual exception.

Comment: @Crowcoder You can see the [sourcecode](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs). It's generally recommended to use ConfigureAwait(false) in libraries so that calling .Result doesn't cause deadlocks. It can also improve performance.

Comment: Can you please post Structure of **CoinMarket** and also what Result you are getting at **JSON.Result**. Then we can help

Comment: Or maybe namespace of the **CoinMarket** is different than what you have defined in your local class

Comment: @Allrameest OP is probably not using that HttpClient for core, but relying on ConfigureAwait(false) [is just a hack](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). We have to stop teaching people bad practices. Even if it doesn't deadlock it is still causing inefficiencies, you should just use a synchronous API.

Comment: @Crowcoder A lot of time it's more inefficient to not call ConfigureAwait(false) since it has to wait for the original context to be free.

Comment: @Allrameest it is always less efficient to have the compiler generate and run all the async infrastructure and then block than it is to use a synchronous API.

Comment: @Crowcoder It looks like `async Main` will just be syntactic sugar for synchronous code anyway:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/

Comment: I guess this would be a bad time to also mention it is bad practice to new up HttpClient for each request? 

Answer (score 1):

You are using json deserializer incorrectly. `DeserializeObject` returns custom object which is not castable to your `List<T>`. This output:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray
SO20171129.CoinData[]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SO20171129.CoinData]
```

is the result of this code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // returns Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray
        var coinMarket = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText("get.json"));
        Console.WriteLine(coinMarket.GetType());
        // returns array of CoinData
        var coinMarketTyped = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CoinData[]>(File.ReadAllText("get.json"));
        Console.WriteLine(coinMarketTyped.GetType());
        // returns List of CoinData
        var coinMarketTyped2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CoinData>>(File.ReadAllText("get.json"));
        Console.WriteLine(coinMarketTyped2.GetType());
    }
}

public class CoinData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }
    public string price_usd { get; set; }
    public string price_btc { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__24h_volume_usd { get; set; }
    public string market_cap_usd { get; set; }
    public string available_supply { get; set; }
    public string total_supply { get; set; }
    public string percent_change_1h { get; set; }
    public string percent_change_24h { get; set; }
    public string percent_change_7d { get; set; }
    public string last_updated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, there is a bunch of online tools which can generate a `POCO` for any `JSON`. I used json2csharp.com for the example above.

Comment: Sounds like you're right. Only weird thing is that @IgorMiquilena got an AggregateException...

Comment: @Allrameest As there is no details on the exception I wouldn't be surprised if there's something like http error for too frequent calls (i.e. DoS protection) as the topic starter was trying to get things working. I got the json from aforementioned url without any issue, although, using IE.

Comment: @Allrameest that is not weird, that is another side effect of `.Result`, it can only throw aggregate exceptions.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, that's a big drawback of using .Result. Async-await is of course prefered.
What I meant was that the serialization bug that Alex pointed out probably don't result in an AggregateException.

Comment: But that could be explained with what Alex said.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your json structure members do not match the CoinMarket class members.

What I would do is to copy the json result and generate the corresponding CoinMarket class on the following website: http://json2csharp.com/

It will output the right CoinMarket class for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class CoinMarket
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }
    public string price_usd { get; set; }
    public string price_btc { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("24h_volume_usd")]
    public string h_volume_usd { get; set; }
    public string market_cap_usd { get; set; }
    public string available_supply { get; set; }
    public string total_supply { get; set; }
    public string percent_change_1h { get; set; }
    public string percent_change_24h { get; set; }
    public string percent_change_7d { get; set; }
    public string last_updated { get; set; }

}
```

}

This is my CoinMarket Class